# Can we split Cassandra Data files?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I am using DataStax version 5.1.7. And I want to create separate data files or directory for each week(7 Days).

Means for each week , it should create a separate data file.

Is it possible ?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for this:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsConfigureCompaction.html

> TimeWindowCompactionStrategy (TWCS)
>
> This strategy is an alternative
> for time series data. TWCS compacts SSTables using a series of time
> windows. While with a time window, TWCS compacts all SSTables flushed
> from memory into larger SSTables using STCS. At the end of the time
> window, all of these SSTables are compacted into a single SSTable.
> Then the next time window starts and the process repeats. The duration
> of the time window is the only setting required. See TWCS compaction
> subproperties. For more information about TWCS, see How is data
> maintained?.

If you choose your timewindow for your needs this should do what you want. A major "feature" of TWCS is that when you have TTLed data all the time after a while a complete sstable can be discarded instead of compacting it again.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Really It is very helpful for me.
Once again Thanks a lot